# Powershell - is `$global:?` a valid way to access`$?`, or something different?

Tags: powershell

In a logfile I've been studying:

```
PS>$global:?
True
```

Now, I know that `$?` is an *automatic* variable, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.4#section-1).

And I have read about *global* variables [here](https://blog.enterprisedna.co/powershell-global-variable/).

I'm not sure if `$?` would count as a global variable as well as an automatic one. If I had multiple Powershell windows open, and if I run

```
PS>fakecommand
```

in one, then `echo $?` would output `False`. However, if I run `echo $?` in a different Powershell window immediately after running the fake command in the first, I get `True`.

This suggests to me (maybe wrongly) that it isn't truly global.

On the other hand, `$global:?` *did* output *something*. When I tried with a variable I knew did not exist:

```
PS>$global:underlay
```

there was no output.

So: Is `$global:?` the same thing as `$?`? If not, when would it be appropriate to use that instead of the usual `$?`?

Comment: `$?` is not a global variable.

Comment: Didn't you see `$?` = `Contains the execution status of the last command. It contains True if the last command succeeded and False if it failed.`

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I did see that, yes. I was testing to see if `$?` in one PowerShell window would contain the state of the last command *even if* that last command was issued in a different window. And it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

> Is `$global:?` the same thing as `$?`

- *Technically*, no: a copy of this variable exists *in every scope* (see details below).
- *In practice*, however, there is **only ever *one* [`$?`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) *value***  and that is the one reflecting the *success status* of the *most recently* executed statement (`$false` if at least one error of any kind occurred, `$true` otherwise), in any scope.

> when would it be appropriate to use that instead of the usual `$?`

- Never: The - automatically managed, read-only - value of `$?` is the *same* in all scopes.

---

###### Background information:

The [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) is defined with the `AllScopes` option (originally in the global scope), which means:

- Whenever a new *descendent* [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes) is created, it receives *its own copy* of the variable, which, however, shares its value with the original variable, so that *all* scopes see the *same (dynamic) value* in their technically separate `$?` copy.<sup>[1]</sup>

To see all properties of the `$?` variable, use [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) as follows - note the `Options` output line, which shows not only `AllScope`, but also `ReadOnly`, implying that `$?` cannot be set *by the user*:<sup>[2]</sup>

```sh
Get-Variable '`?' | Format-List
```

Output:

```sh
Value       : True
Name        : ?
Description : Status of last command
Visibility  : Public
Module      : 
ModuleName  : 
Options     : ReadOnly, AllScope
Attributes  : {}
```

Note:

- The variable name, `?`, must be passed as `` '`?' ``, because `Get-Variable` invariably interprets its (positionally implied) `-Name` argument(s) as [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards). Thus,  in order for `?` to be used *literally*, escaping with `` ` `` is needed.

---

<sup>[1] `$?` is truly seen with the same value in *all* scopes, even across *[module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules) boundaries*. In general, however, note that each module has its own scope domain (stack of scopes, aka "session state"), and `AllScope` variables from *outside* a module or from a *different* module are *not* copied to a given module (because the given module's scopes aren't *descendants* of the caller's scope).

An `AllScope` variable defined in the *global* scope - as `$?` is - is a special case: while such variables are *not* copied to modules, modules *directly see the global copy*, thanks to PowerShell's dynamic scoping, because modules are linked to the global scope, without being *descendants* of the latter.</sup>

<sup>[2] However, providing *some* mechanism for user code to set this variable is being discussed - see the relevant comment in [GitHub issue #10917](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10917#issuecomment-550550490).

Even though you shouldn't be able to, *inside modules* you *can* assign to `$?`, which creates a regular, module-local variable by that name (this is possible, because - as explained in the previous footnote - the global `ReadOnly, AllScope` options variable is *not* copied to modules). However, this assigned value is only available via `` Get-Variable '`?'` -ValueOnly ``, whereas querying `$?` - despite not using a scope specifier - apparently *always* refers to the *global* copy of the variable.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think that `$?` just ignores this context attribute.

I have tested both `$global:?` and `$private:?` and `$?` and they
all function in an identical manner.